# Moving ImageView to the Right of layout

Tags: java, android, xml, maps

I have 4 imageviews connected each other with "toLeftOf" command. The problem is when I make one of them Invisible the other staying at the same position or going to left side of layout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" >

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ahmetbesli.eczanem.MapsActivity" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="85dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/direction"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_black_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bullet"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_format_align_left_black_24dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/direction"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/direction"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bullet"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bullet"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/access"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_accessibility_black_24dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/share"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/share"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I used animateLayoutChanges = "true" but it did not work. And this is how make them invisible or visible.

```
if (!marker.getTitle().equals("Buradasın")) {
                    latLngMaps = marker.getPosition();
                    share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    direction.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bullet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    access.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    bullet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    direction.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    access.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
```

What want to do is lets say they are staying like   X Y Z Q
when I make Y invisible It must be like X Z Q. It will just go through the invisible's place. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace it with a `LinearLayout` with an orientation `horizontal`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/direction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_black_24dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bullet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_format_align_left_black_24dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/access"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_accessibility_black_24dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And set the visibility to `GONE` instead of `INVISIBLE`:

```
            if (!marker.getTitle().equals("Buradasın")) {
                latLngMaps = marker.getPosition();
                share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                direction.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bullet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                access.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                bullet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                share.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                direction.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                access.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```

Comment: It worked. How can i move all the images to the right ? they standing at the left side now.

Comment: I don't know what your app does, and if it applies, but `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` on your `LinearLayout` attributes should do it (this flag will apply no matter if the language of the user is right to left or left to right)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the views do not fill the space when it is hidden, you should use `GONE` instead of `INVISIBLE`.

```
 access.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Visibility.html\

**UPDATE**

Replace the container of the imageview layouts, replace this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="85dp">
```

By this :

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="85dp">
```

Comment: it's still same. the imageview that stays visible is going to the left